# UIWebView does not loads after any unsuccessful login

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am loading a url which has authentication So I used the following code

```
BOOL _authed = NO;
NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *mChallenge;
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request      navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

{

```
NSLog(@"Did start loading: %@ auth:%d", [[request URL] absoluteString], _authed);

  if (!_authed) {
        _authed = NO;

         [NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

         return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge;
{
    NSLog(@"got auth challange");


   _authed = YES;        
   mChallenge = challenge;

    UIAlertView *prompt = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:@"Authentication Required" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Login", nil];
    prompt.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput;
    [prompt show];


}
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(buttonIndex == 1){
        UITextField *usernameField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        UITextField *passwordField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:1];
        NSString *userName = usernameField.text;
        NSString *password = passwordField.text;
        NSLog(@"%@, %@",userName,password);

        [[mChallenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:userName password:password persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:mChallenge];
    }
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response;
{


    NSLog(@"response %@",response);
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL       URLWithString:@"http://mysharepointurl.aspx"]];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];


}
- (BOOL)connectionShouldUseCredentialStorage:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    return NO;
}
```

this works fine if I try correct password first time.
But when I try with wrong credential first time, the prompt comes again and then I try with correct credential, then web view will not be loaded

any advice on this

Comment: where your changing the _authed = YES.

Comment: Its in didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge, Failed to copy when posting the question, now its edited. I am getting prompt to enter credential if I try with wrong credential,